# Mongoose.js, error when trying to update a model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Im using the module mongoose.js for my mongodb database. My data base looks like this:

```
{
  thing1: "thing1",
  thing2: "thing2",
  boolean: false
}
```

I want to update it and put `false`.
I tried this:

```
const model = await myModel.find({ thing1: "thing1", thing2: "thing2" });
await model.update({ boolean: true });
```

But it output an error:

```
model.update is not a function
```

I imported mongoose, i imported myModel, the connexion to the database is good, what should i do to fix it?

Comment: I think you forgot to `await` at `myModel.find`

Comment: here yes, not in my code, sorry

Comment: If you use `.findOne` instead of `.find`, you'll get a document where you are able to call `.update` on, *if such document exists*. So it would be wise if you check whether the document is `null` before calling `.update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model.update` can only be done when you are updating directly and its first parameter is query element and next is the update value with $set operator. Your code should be like this
`await myModel.findOneAndUpdate({thing1: "thing1", thing2: "thing2"},{$set:{boolean:true}})`

Comment: i just tried it, there is no error but it didn't update the document

Comment: If that doesn' t work, try this querying first method. `let model=await myModel.findOne({thing1: "thing1", thing2: "thing2"})`
    `model.boolean=true`
    `await model.save()` If these two methods doesn't work, then there is someother problem in your code.